# Run synchronous pull in Google Cloud Pub/Sub with the Python client API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I can't find the *returnImmediately* flag in the Python client API. 
Is there any specific reason for that? 
Is there another way to pull queued message synchronously from a subscription in Python?

Answer (score 5):

Google doesn't provide something like this. But you can easily workaround it by implementing your own Queue

```
from Queue import Queue

from google.cloud import pubsub

subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
topic = "projects/newproject-xxxxx/topics/tarunlalwani"
subscription_name = 'projects/newproject-xxxxx/subscriptions/sub1'

class SynchronousSubscription(object):

    def callback(self, message):
        print(message.data)
        message.ack()
        self.pending_messages.put(message)

    def __init__(self, subscription):
        self.subscription_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, self.callback)
        self.pending_messages = Queue()

    def consume_sync(self):
        return self.pending_messages.get()

sub = SynchronousSubscription(subscription_name)
data = sub.consume_sync()
```

And it does work great for me when I tested

[image: Working Example]

Comment: what theme in VS Code is that btw? looks great!

Comment: @cryanbhu thats pycharm IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on previous answer:

Currently there exists a function with desired functionality, here is the piece of documentation from [subscriber_client.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/google/cloud/gapic/pubsub/v1/subscriber_client.py#L662):

```
def pull(self,
         subscription,
         max_messages,
         return_immediately=None,
         options=None):
    ...
Args:
    ...
      return_immediately (bool): If this field set to true, the system 
        will respond immediately even if
        it there are no messages available to return in the ``Pull`` response.
        Otherwise, the system may wait (for a bounded amount of time) until at
        least one message is available, rather than returning no messages. The
        client may cancel the request if it does not wish to wait any longer for
        the response.
```

But the execution, read [this comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4338#issuecomment-342309349) first, returns two exceptions(the one I present is an aggregate of two):

> RetryError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified
>   as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with
>   (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, A required argument is missing in the
>   request: (argument="max_messages").)>)

There is a [related issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4338#issuecomment-342212239) if you want more details.

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Pub/Sub client library does not directly expose the pull method, instead offering an asynchronous API designed for efficiently receiving messages. If you have specific reasons to want to call the synchronous pull method (including using the returnImmediately property), then you'll need to generate the gRPC-based library. You will need to fetch the [service definition](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto) and then [generate the client](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html#creating-the-client). Alternatively, you can make an HTTP request using the [REST API version of pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull).

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud's previous official `gcloud` python library (last version was 0.18.3, available in pip) ***does*** have stable support for pull functions in idiomatic python.  Although the Cloud Pub/Sub API is GA and thus this deprecated library *should* be stable, be aware that this library won't be getting any updates.  I've used it extensively in the past two years without incident.

```
from gcloud import pubsub

# Connect to pubsub
client = pubsub.Client(project='myproject')

topic = client.topic('mytopic')
sub = topic.subscription('mysub')
if not topic.exists():
    topic.create()
if not sub.exists():
    sub.create()

# In your code, use a try-except for this pull and handle failures appropriately
recv = sub.pull(return_immediately=False, max_messages=1)

ack_id, msg = recv[0]

msg_attribute = msg.attributes['myattribute']
msg_data = msg.data

sub.acknowledge([ack_id, ])
```